# How to use timeago plugin with its settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeago

I am using jquery timeago plugin.
I am using it like this :

```
timeAgo = "2013-09-10 16:41:14.671";
timeAgo = jQuery.timeago(timeAgo);
```

The output of above code is "about 23 hours ago".I dont want the about word before. and few more setting.How do I use the plugin with its settings.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: yes but i am not able to understand how to do that.

Comment: You need to change the `strings` inside the plugin to what you want and remove the 'about' part.

Comment: Try `$.trim(timeAgo.replace('about',''));`